# I need to know where these Android icons came from!

Tags: android

I was wandering what icons both quick settings and battery doctor use ( the settings icons like wifi, etc ). Are they free, they seem to be since their both using them? Are they ones supplied by google or custom? or are they referencable from android.R.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some general information about android icons:

There are built-in icons that android uses, which are in `android.R.drawable` and stored in the file system corresponding to that location. Google discouraged referencing these icons directly, instead asking you to store a local copy of them in case they change in future android versions.

That and more information about making icons here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

You can also find free icon sets online, like here:
http://androgeek.com/android-icon-packs-basics-and-a-list-of-free-icon-sets.html

Other links:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi
http://androiddrawables.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can find them in Android's source code (check out https://source.android.com and https://android.googlesource.com).
They are part of the Android Open Source Project and you can use them in your applications.